# distorted video playback with vlc in kubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, radeon, vlc, video-player

I recently installed kubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. Everything works fine except that i can't play videos with vlc player! the default player(Dragon) has no problem but when i open videos with vlc the only thing i see is a pink screen with video playing underneath. My graphic card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670 and i haven't install the driver because of the conflict with kernel version. but i didn't install the driver in older versions and everything worked just fine.

Except the video playback issue, i have no Graphic related problems in plasma and everything works smoothly.

I have to mention that i installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ffmpeg` and `gstreamer` codecs.

I would really appreciate it if you would help me to fix this problem, because without vlc, life is really hard! I'm just wondering if it's some package(codec) problem or vlc can't adapt to this version yet! or, its because of my graphic card driver.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You actually don't even have to install, because your driver is somewhere inside your `xserver-xorg-driver-*` package, which comes with the x server. Also, try with mplayer and see if that works (use multiple outputs like -vo x11, use -vo help to list all)

Comment: yup! mplayer(smplayer) works perfectly fine! so it must be vlc's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found a Solution that Somehow fix the Problem. By Setting this Option

```
Preferences > Input/Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding
```

to "disabled" you Can fix the rendering. It's still too slow for Hi-res Videos but works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the new amdgpu graphics drivers, i have problems with vlc on Ubuntu 16.04, wen i forward or backward the video, it's freeze for 3 seconds but the audio it's keep running,  now I'm using smplayer, just change the icons, they are horrible...

Comment: yeah! after playing a little bit with smplayer, i found out that it's as powerful as vlc, maybe more. i agree with you the ui is a litlle...but it's superfast and works just flawlessly.